# Group by max value

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица юзеров. Так получилось что в ней есть юзеры с одинаковым email. Мне надо выбрать всех уникальных (по email) юзеров с максимальной датой регистрации (последнего зарегистрированного). Я пытался это сделать вот так, но не работает - выбирает первого:

```
select id, email, created_at as created_at 
from users
group by email
having max(created_at)
```

Тот же пример на [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9419/5).

Comment: Интересно, а created_at в качестве timestamp, т.е. количества секунд от unix-time, хранится? Или там другой тип / формат?

Comment: @gil9red не понял вопроса. Дата хранится как поле типа int в котором записан timestamp. Все предельно просто...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать сперва отсортировать данные, а потом группировать, например так:

```
select id, email, from_unixtime(created_at) as created_at
from ( SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY created_at DESC) users_ord
group by email
```

а having тут не подойдет, это уже фильтрация результата после группировки

Comment: Сработало, спасибо!

Comment: А если мне надо еще одно условие? Вот [так например](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c55770/1). Т.е. добавился флаг is_active. Надо помимо сортировки по дате создания выбрать в первую очередь активных юзеров (но если только неактивный останется то его тоже брать).

Comment: И еще абсолютно тот же пример, но с использованием вьюх (у меня много данных и мне так удобнее) уже не работает почему-то :( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a7eb/2 (две вьюхи пришлось сделать потому что во вьюхах нельзя делать подзапросы увы)

Comment: select id, email, from_unixtime(created_at) as created_at 
from (select * from users where is_active = 1 order by created_at desc) as u
group by email
having count(id) > 1
union all
select id, email, from_unixtime(created_at) as created_at 
from users
group by email
having count(id) = 1

Comment: Чет плохо понял зачем там `union`, но если всем юзерам выставить `is_active = 0` то ничего не находит - а значит работает неверно (должно все-равно одного найти - последнего зарегистрированного)

Comment: Все оказалось куда проще, надо было лишь добавить это поле тоже в сортировку: `order by is_active desc, created_at desc`. Но со вьюхами до сих пор не ясно в чем проблема...