# Group by не работает со вьюхой

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table users
(
  id int,
  email varchar(100),
  is_active tinyint(1),
  created_at int
);

insert into users values (1, 'user@mail.ru', 1, unix_timestamp());
insert into users values (2, 'user@mail.ru', 1, unix_timestamp() + 1234);
insert into users values (3, 'user@mail.ru', 0, unix_timestamp() + 123456);

create view ordered_users as
select * from users order by is_active desc, created_at desc;

select id, email, created_at as created_at 
from ordered_users
group by email
```

Выводит запись с id = 1, а должно с id = 2. Причем обычным запросом:

```
select id, email, created_at as created_at 
from (select * from users order by is_active desc, created_at desc) as u
group by email
```

Выводит верно id = 2. Но мне надо именно вьюхой!!! Подскажите в чем проблема? Почему группировка при выборе из вьюхи не работает? Тот же пример на [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/911eed/1).

Comment: @Mike Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76699/discussion-between-dark-byte-and-mike).

Answer (score 1):

Вы задавали уже [похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/824330/415197).

Та же ошибка - вы полагаетесь на случайность, а не сортируете конечный результат выборки. То, что вы получаете из выборки, вполне ожидаемый результат.

Поробуйте добавить:

```
...
group by email
order by is_active desc, created_at desc
```

И результаты всех ваших запросов не будут отличаться.

Answer (score -1):

Честно сказать, удивлён как у вас вообще это отработало, вы используете объединение а затем выводите все поля. Быть может вы хотели сделать так?

```
select max(id), email, max(created_at)  as created_at 
from ordered_users
where is_active = 1
group by email
```

Comment: Извините, но что это за дичь? Нет, я так не хотел. Вообще не то. И я не использовал нигде объединение (union).

Comment: я поправил ответ, неправильно запомнил имя поля

Comment: Эта тема - продолжение вот [этой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/820272/group-by-max-value). Там подробно описано что я хочу сделать. В частности в комментариях к ответу.