# Почему во вьюхах order by всегда срабатывает после group by?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table users
(
  id int,
  email varchar(100),
  is_active tinyint(1),
  created_at int
);

insert into users values (1, 'user1@mail.ru', 1, unix_timestamp());
insert into users values (2, 'user1@mail.ru', 1, unix_timestamp() + 1234);
insert into users values (3, 'user1@mail.ru', 0, unix_timestamp() + 123456);
insert into users values (4, 'user2@mail.ru', 1, unix_timestamp());
insert into users values (5, 'user2@mail.ru', 1, unix_timestamp() + 1234);
insert into users values (6, 'user2@mail.ru', 0, unix_timestamp() + 123456);
```

[Пример с запросом](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ab553/2):

```
select * // выбрались записи с id: 2 и 5 (как мне и надо было)
from 
(
  select *
  from users
  order by is_active desc, created_at desc
) u
group by email
```

[Пример во вьюхами](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7078fb6/3):

```
create view ordered_users as
select * from users order by is_active desc, created_at desc;

create view unique_users as
select * from ordered_users group by email;

select * // выбрались записи с id: 1 и 4 (неверно)
from unique_users
```

В случае с подзапросом `order by` выполняется в подзапросе, а уже потом из него делается выборка с группировкой. А в случае со вьюхами сначала выполняется `group by`... Я никак не могу понять почему так происходит?

И еще, равносилен ли первый запрос вот [этому](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ab553/1)? В смысле всегда ли результат будет одинаковым? Просто у меня был этот запрос, но я его переписал как мне показалось попроще.

```
select * from users // выбирается тоже самое что в первом случае
where id in 
(
  select 
  (
    select id 
    from users u 
    where u.email = x.email 
    order by is_active desc, created_at desc 
    limit 1
  ) 
  from (select distinct email from users) as x
)
```

P.S. Если вдруг непонятно: надо выбрать всех уникальных (по email) юзеров которые активны (но если только неактивные то их тоже надо выбирать!!!) и последние по регистрации.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77153/discussion-on-question-by-dark-byte----order-by--).

Comment: В представлениях запрещено использовать ORDER BY, ибо это виртуальная таблица.

Comment: @msi кем? Вами? Ничего там не запрещено. Чушь.

Comment: Стандартом. Если MySQL это позволяет, то, вероятно, это никак не влияет ни на что.

Comment: @msi возьмите и запустите код. Я не собираюсь доказывать очевидное.

Comment: Чем меньше знаешь, тем крепче спишь.

Comment: @msi. В mySql order by ограниченно может быть использован в view. Выдержка из документации: "_ORDER BY is permitted in a view definition, but it is ignored if you select from a view using a statement that has its own ORDER BY._". И да, так как внешний group by для своей реализации использует скрытую сортировку MySQL вполне может проигнорировать внутренний order by, как и сказано в документации

Comment: @Mike, не сомневаюсь, что это так. Однако не вижу в этом нарушении стандарта никаких преимуществ. Для меня это еще один минус на счет MySQL, учитывая еще и то, что многие считают, что SQL и MySQL - это одно и то же. :-)

Answer (score 1):

По стандарту SQL только последняя сортировка гарантирует порядок записей в выборке.

У вас она отсутствует и порядок во всех ваших результатах случаен. То есть, тот результат, который вы получаете и считаете правильным, не гарантируется. Вы перейдёте на более новую версию, и он станет другим. Убедитесь сами, [в 8-ой версии](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e6a9a7945b015080153d8c4bfbb5a9b4) ваш запрос вообще не работает.

Answer (score 1):

Тут всё просто - результат последний операции перепишет "правильно" отсортирооованный результат предыдущей.

Поэтому в представлениях или позапросх никто order by не включает, потому что он в большинстве случаев будет просто безсмысленным. Вот какой смысл сортировать внутренний запрос, если при групироовке он будет заново пересортирован по другому столбцу:

```
from 
(
  select *
  from users
  order by is_active desc, created_at desc
) u group by email
```

Обычно база данных замечает эту нестыковку и не сортирует результат подзапроса вообще.