# Почему вьюха и запрос расходятся в результатах?

Tags: mysql, sql

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/336e89/1)

Мне непонятно, почему в указанном запросе из вьюхи возвращается только одна запись?
При том, что тот же код этой вьюхи с тем же условием возвращает уже две записи.

Сильно подозреваю, что это как-то связано с порядком `group by` и `where` при использовании вьюхи. У меня уже были какие-то похожие проблемы [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/820574/176064) и [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/824330/176064).

Структура:

- `articles(id, name)`
- `authors(id, name)`
- `jobs(id, name)`
- `authors_connection(article_id, author_id, job_id)`

ссылки соответственно `article_id` на таблицу `article` стобец `id`, `author_id` на `authors.id`, `job_id` на `jobs.id`.

У одной статьи может быть несколько авторов. У одного автора может быть несколько мест работы, но на выходе вьюхи должно остаться только одно любое. Вьюха объединяет эти разрозненные таблицы в одну таблицу авторов с одним указанным местом работы.

Comment: правильно и подозреваете. вы там зачем вообще группировку используете, если у вас нет никаких агрегатных функций? Такой синтаксис работает наверное только в mysql, и вообще не определяет, какая строка останется на выходе, хотя наверное в основном остается первая из группы

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/599802/194569

Comment: @teran затем чтобы исключить дублирование авторов. Дело в том что мест работы у одного автора может быть несколько, но мне надо взять только первое.

Comment: вы где то с документации читали, что группировка применяется для того, чтобы исключать дублирования и с ее помощью можно получить что-то первое? Дублирование исключается иными средствами, как и извлечение первой записи (если существует какой-то порядок).

Comment: @teran хм, я почему-то всегда использую `group by` для удаления дубликатов... А что вы предложите? `distinct`?

Comment: @DarkByte я уже удалил коммент, да. в любом случае, Опишите в вопросе, какие сущности у вас используются, какие связи между ними, и что вы хотите получить на выходе. Пока что мы видим, что вы хотите применить неподходящий инструмент, и когда он работает не совсем так, вы хотите это починить. Хотя на самом деле решение должно быт другим.

Comment: @teran мне казалось структура понятна из кода, но я добавил в вопрос краткое описание.

Comment: ну в таком виде, конечно, понятно. Я имел в виду, описание самой модели. Что есть у вас статьи, есть авторы, которые пишут эти статьи. Авто может писать много статей, и статьи пишутся авторами совместно. А вот что такое jobjs, и что по итогу вы хотите вывести как результат, мне не особо ясно.

Comment: @teran так лучше?

Comment: Имеется в виду, что например автор работает в разных издательствах, и в одном пишет одну статью, в другом другую? Или ученый работает в двух в научных организациях и в каждой пишет по статье? А по какому принципу нужно оставлять одно место работы из всех?

Comment: @teran один автор может быть привязан только к одной статье. Если он будет писать новую статью он заново вбивает свои данные и создается новая запись автора (знаю решение так себе). У места работы в данном случае нет какого-то конкретного критерия выбора. Можно просто взять первое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql нарушает стандарт в плане нестрогой группировки.
В последних версиях она ещё и отключена по умолчанию.

Добавьте все используемые поля в `GROUP BY` (*либо уберите GROUP BY вообще*) и получите идентичный результат (2 записи) при запросе из View

```
create view v_authors as
select author_id as id, c.article_id, p.name, j.name as job_name
from authors_connection c
inner join articles a on a.id = c.article_id
inner join authors p on p.id = c.author_id
left join jobs j on j.id = c.job_id
group by c.author_id, c.article_id, p.name, j.name; -- Тут
```

С другой стороны, очевидно, что запрос без view работает только потому, что фильтр применяется **до группировки**.

Запрос:

```
select * from(
  select author_id as id, c.article_id, p.name, j.name as job_name
  from authors_connection c
  inner join articles a on a.id = c.article_id
  inner join authors p on p.id = c.author_id
  left join jobs j on j.id = c.job_id
  group by c.author_id
) t where article_id = 3
```

также вернёт одну запись (скорее всего, это похоже на UB).
Таким образом, придётся вынести группировку из view.
Или, в процессе группировки Вы потеряете данные, по которым собираетесь фильтровать.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79486/discussion-on-answer-by-vp-arth-------).

Answer (score 1):

Вам следует ознакомится [с ответом @Mike относительно использования `group by`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/599802/223826)

Что происходит в ваших запросах.

Если вы выполните запрос без `where` и `group by`:

```
select author_id as id, c.article_id, p.name, j.name as job_name
from authors_connection c
inner join articles a on a.id = c.article_id
inner join authors p on p.id = c.author_id
left join jobs j on j.id = c.job_id;
```

то получите набор из 4 строк: 3 статьи первого автора и статья #3 второго.

Далее при работе со вьюшкой вы проводите группировку по автору. В результате чего у вас остается 2 строки. Второй автор там как был с третьей статьей так и остался, а вот группировка первого автор дает вам неопределенный результат. У вас было три строки этого автора, а после группировки остается одна. Какая из них именно остается - не определено, т.к. группировка в целом выполнена неправильно.
Осталась первая попавшаяся, и это вероятно строка с `arcticle_id = 1`.
Поэтому после фильтрации вьюшки по `article_id = 3` осталась единственная строка второго автора. При удачном расположении звезд этот запрос может вернуть и 2 строки, если после группировки останется не произвольная первая строка первого автора, а третья. Индекс там по убыванию будет, или еще чего.

Во втором же случае из полных четырех строк вы сначала фильтруете статьи с `id = 3`, остается две строки разных авторов. И теперь при группировке остается все те же две разных строки.

Comment: Да, именно про расположение звёзд я и хотел сказать))

Answer (score 1):

В mysql *почти нет* параметризованных отображений.

Однако, есть довольно известный хак, с функцией и переменной:

```
create function param1() returns INTEGER NO SQL return @param1;

create view v_authors as
select author_id as id
  , c.article_id
  , min(p.name) name
  , min(j.name) as job_name
from authors_connection c
inner join articles a on a.id = c.article_id
inner join authors p on p.id = c.author_id
left join jobs j on j.id = c.job_id
where c.article_id = param1()
group by c.author_id, c.article_id;
```

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sSEqQwSqxVm7Ao66xAcqop/1)

Comment: Ничосе О_о Нефига не понял))))) Это что за магия такая еще? Получается что эта функция как-бы запоминает последний присвоенный (???) результат и всегда его возвращает?

Comment: Почти, вью зависит от функции, в которой возвращается текущее значение переменной. Флаги в функции убеждают движок кешировать(? хм) её результат.

Comment: Я запутался про DETERMINISTIC)) Но похоже оно тут ни на что не влияет(мб, производительность? Чтобы не обращаться к переменной для каждой строки).

Comment: Попробую выяснить) [Задал вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/847834/176064)

Comment: А что значит `NO SQL`?

Comment: Это просто указание на то, что в функции нет sql выражений)

Comment: На самом деле если подумать мне это все-таки не особо подходит. Т.е. это вьюха заточенная под одно условие. Но это сейчас мне нужно было, а потом может еще какое-нибудь потребуется. Да и вообще запрашивать ее все-время с этим параметром неудобно... Что если мне надо все элементы получить из этой вьюхи? Не... Не то это.

Comment: Для начала, следует ответить на вопрос - "А зачем вообще вам VIEW?"

Comment: Я использую вьюхи как перевалочный пункт при мерже баз данных с одинаковой структурой. Очень удобно надо сказать. Когда-то вначале (это не первая моя задача такого рода) я пытался сливать все из php, но так выходило в разы больше кода и я внезапно открыл для себя вьюхи. После чего полностью взвалил эту задачу на sql.