# function - Смысл флага deterministic

Tags: mysql, sql, функции

В чём разница между детерменированной и недетерминированной функцией?
Я надеялся, что deterministic заставит СУБД посчитать функцию **чистой** и закеширует её результат?

> The `DETERMINISTIC` clause for functions is ideal for functions that do
>   not have any non-deterministic components. This means that each time
>   you provide the function with the same parameter values, the result is
>   the same. When you define a function you can simply add the
>   `DETERMINISTIC` option to the declaration section, making sure that the
>   function (or any functions or procedures it calls) does not depend on
>   the state of session variables or schema objects as the [results may
>   vary across invocations](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/function.htm). This option instructs the optimizer that it
>   may use a cached result whenever it encounters a previously calculated
>   result.
>   [Source](http://oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plsql/cache/alternatives/deterministic.html)

```
create function det() returns INTEGER DETERMINISTIC NO SQL return @param;

create function ndet() returns INTEGER NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL return @param;

select 
  @param:=5, det() d1, ndet() n1
, @param:=3, det() d2, ndet() n2
, @param:=1, det() d3, ndet() n3
, @param:=7, det() d4, ndet() n4;
```

Результат:

> 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 7

Т.е. я не вижу никакой разницы.

Как понять, в чём разница, и в каких ситуациях она проявляется?

Comment: С чего вы взяли, что должно кешировать результат? -это влияет в основном на репликацию, `DETERMINISTIC` можно записать в двоичный журнал прямо в виде выражения, а `NON DETERMINISTIC` можно
записывать только в виде `row-based` - иначе на реплике могут получиться другие данные.

Comment: @And, на мой взгляд `deterministic function` - синоним `pure function`. Добавил в вопрос цитату про Oracle

Comment: @vp_arth сами себе противоречите :D Вы же только что мне ответили что они не синонимы. Во всяком случае не полностью.

Comment: @DarkByte, просто "синоним" в этом комментарии не является синонимом к "синониму" в том. Я думаю, что Вы придираетесь и совершенно прозрачно понимаете, что я имел в виду в каждом из этих случаев.

Comment: @vp_arth `"синоним" в этом комментарии не является синонимом к "синониму" в том` ШТА??? О_о Я не придираюсь. Просто вы действительно себе противоречите.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы определяете `DETERMINISTIC`, это значит, что для одних и тех же параметров функция всегда возвращает одно и то же значение. Соответственно, MySQL по-идее может кешировать значение, чтобы не пересчитывать его для одних и тех же параметров.

Но поддержка `DETERMINISTIC` в MySQL реализована не полностью, функция будет выполняться всегда.

Пример на MySQL 5.7.22:

```
create function rr() returns INTEGER DETERMINISTIC return RAND()*1000;
select rr(), rr();
+------+------+
| rr() | rr() |
+------+------+
|  300 |  451 |
+------+------+
```

Во `WHERE` выполняется 1 раз:

```
CREATE FUNCTION r1() returns INTEGER DETERMINISTIC return RAND()*3;

SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 1 AS ID UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS ID UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS ID UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS ID UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 AS ID
) AS t1
WHERE r1() < ID;
```

Выведет, например, `1 | 2 | 3`, то есть без "выпадов".

Comment: Последнее предложение... Не могли бы вы добавить пруф?

Comment: Пруфа не нашел. Слышал на внутреннем обучении относительно 5.5 версии. В новостях "мы это пофиксили" не пробегало.

Comment: Жаль. Потому как это всё объясняет.

Answer (score 2):

По-моему в таком виде обе функции заведомо недетерминированы, т.к. зависят от **внешней** переменной `@param`, которая не является параметром функции...

если оформить функцию так:

```
create function det(param INTEGER) returns INTEGER DETERMINISTIC NO SQL return param;
```

то ее (по-моему) можно считать детерменированной, т.к. она гарантированно вернет одинаковый результат при вызове с одинаковыми параметрами...

Comment: Разве mysql проверяет самостоятельно, что флаг был передан некорректно? Каким образом? Видел в документации, что mysql доверяет пользователю в этом вопросе и поэтому результаты могут отличаться от ожидаемых (вероятно имелось в виду "неожиданное кеширование"?)

Comment: Судя по документации MySQL не может проверить является ли функция указанная как `DETERMINISTIC` таковой на самом деле... Я не совсем понял что вы пытаетесь сделать...

Comment: Я хочу обмануть mysql в этом плане. Пусть считает функцию детерминированной и игнорирует изменения переменной(ведь она не может проверить?). Как заставить mysql посчитать функцию чистой и возвращать закешированный результат первого вызова?

Comment: MySQL does not check that a routine declared DETERMINISTIC is free of statements that produce nondeterministic results. [Пруф](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html)

Comment: @MaxU хотите сказать что ФП-шная чистота функций и детерминированность это синонимы?

Comment: @TotalPusher, да, но вот как это сочетается с тем, что они его вообще не реализовали? Или документацию написали о том, "как должно быть", а до реализации так и не дошло?  =)

Comment: Для бинлога это как-то учитывается. А оптимизатор запросов - нет. Хранимые в мускуле в зачаточном состоянии. Вполне возможно, что документацию написали, тесты сделали, а реализовать - не сделали :)

Comment: @DarkByte, почти. Все чистые функции - детерминированны, но не все детерминированные - чистые. В чистых ещё есть условие про отсутствие сторонних эффектов(как то, лог в файл и т.п.)

Comment: [Старый закрытый баг про хранимые в WHERE](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=29338)